# Mesh is having trouble following bones correctly

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

My Character has been plagued by several strange problems with its parenting to its bones.

[image: My character]

First of all, his eyes are not moving with his head correctly. Every other solution I've looked up said it had something to do with the eyes not being weight painted correctly, but I've checked, double checked, triple checked, and heptoplole checked, and the head has them 100% red while no other bone has any red on them.

[image: Eyes not right]

Also, the armature won't let me rename the bones. Each one reacts differently, but usually the mesh won't move with it fully anymore and it deforms to some degree. The head is the worst.

[image: Renaming problem]

My blend file can be found here: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43706
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "pirate" head looks better in my blender:

[image]

but the head, at least, moves wrongly because you are not seeing bones axis rotation, in stick mode: try octahedron mode:

[image]

but I also inspected weight influences, and some bones have slight influence on the head, too, so do a complete check again, maybe.

I always reccomend to get help from custom weight paint color to help visualize difficult wrong spots...

[image]

see this other old (my) answer about it: [When IK bone moved wrong part of mesh deforms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42020/when-ik-bone-moved-wrong-part-of-mesh-deforms/42049?s=2|0.3664#42049)

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply! This pretty much fixed the problem.