# vertices rotating with bone even when there is no visible weight painting

Tags: armature, weight-painting

[image]

While weight painting today I ran into an issue I've never come across before. I was weight painting for the clavicle bone when I started having vertices that would rotate with the bone but had no visible weight painting. I spent over an hour hiding faces and making sure everything had no weight paint value. I also tried unassigning the specific vertices from the vertex groups. Been stuck on this for about 4 hours now. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Hi, if geometry moves with bones, there are weights (remmber they could be even for other bones of the armature...) see if this helps, too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42020/when-ik-bone-moved-wrong-part-of-mesh-deforms/42049#42049